# Remove non-english string from Rows: R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a couple of variables whose data (rows) contain english string followed by non-english translation (Hindi).

E.g. Carpenter (Hindi word for carpenter)

Is there a way to strip the rows to contain only the english part? Hindi is causing problems with applying functions and so I want them removed.

Comment: Are the Hindi words always encased in parentheses? Also could you provide a working dataset that has more examples.

Comment: Something like this: Construction  Labourer(सभी प्रकार के निर्माण मजदूर). And others have some english after the hindi  and the parenthesis. 

E.g. Other(उपरोक्त के अतिरिक्त) - WELDER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option using base R's `iconv()` which removes only the non-Latin script:

```
s <- 'Carpenter (बढ़ई)'
iconv(s, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")
# [1] "Carpenter ()"
```

Applying to a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(rbind('Carpenter (बढ़ई)',
    'Cat (बिल्ली)'))
sapply(df,iconv, from="latin1", to="ASCII",sub="")
# [1,] "Carpenter ()"                           
# [2,] "Cat ()"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. The only problem is that the resulting output is not a data frame. Not sure how to preserve the structure of the data frame.

Comment: Glad it works! Try placing it within `data.frame()`, i.e. `data.frame(sapply(df,iconv, from="latin1", to="ASCII",sub=""))`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to strip the english part of the text by using regular expressions (regex) and the `stringr` package. Below is an example data frame and resulting output.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(
      complete_wrd = c(
             "carpenter (Hindi word for carpenter)",
             "cat (Hindi word for cat)",
             "dog (Hindi word for dog)"))


df %>%
   mutate(engl_wrd = stringr::str_extract(complete_wrd, "^.*?\\S*"))


# A tibble: 3 x 2
  complete_wrd                         engl_wrd 
  <chr>                                <chr>    
1 carpenter (Hindi word for carpenter) carpenter
2 cat (Hindi word for cat)             cat      
3 dog (Hindi word for dog)             dog
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have provided some examples along with the questions. I still see hindi in the brackets. So I'm not sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
mutate(hindi_text = str_remove(hindi_text, "\\(.*\\)"))
#             hindi_text
# 1 Construction Labourer
# 2                Other
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(hindi_text = c("Construction Labourer(सभी प्रकार के निर्माण मजदूर)", "Other(उपरोक्त के अतिरिक्त) "))
```